# Who's the "Lavender" coffee shop manager?

Tags: crayon-shin-chan

There are episodes where the 5-year-old Himawari appeared from a dark cloud. She often visited the "Lavender" coffee shop at the end of each episode, and I wonder what's the relationship between the manager and her.

Who's the "Lavender" coffee shop manager?